# Azure PHP web role, F# worker role: developing on different machines

Tags: php, azure, f#, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

A friend and I would like to create a website to manipulate Facebook data.

The structure is:

- a PHP web role (contains the web page, user OAuth login, interacts with queues, and interacts with SQL Azure database)
- an F# worker role (does statistics and quite heavy data extractions)

The process is (assuming a new user):

- user arrives on the web page and logs onto Facebook via OAuth, the PHP web role then posts a message in a worktodo queue with the login info and token.
- F# worker role reads the message off the worktodo queue and starts doing data crunching (using the Facebook API) and stats, then it writes the results to a SQL Azure database. Finally it posts a message to the workdone queue stating it has succeeded in doing the data processing for the user.
- Finally the PHP web role reads the workdone queue and notices the work is done, and displays the algorithm results.

I have two questions:

- Is there a big flaw in this design?
- What is the best way to collaborate: one person will write the PHP and another the F#, is there a way to use development storage from two different machines?

Thanks a lot! (Apologies if some find this stuff too basic, I am very much a beginner in all these matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with this plan.

I don't think there's a way to have two machines pointing at the same development storage, but you can just use cloud storage (even when running locally).  I do that all of the time; you will pay for bandwidth and storage transactions, but for most apps in testing, this cost is trivial.

Comment: I am having a problem with how the worker role lets the web role know it is done. The queue thing will not work unless there is a queue for each user(otherwise lots of messages not related to the user). I could check the datbase to see if has been filled for the user (with a timer), or I could create a blob when the work is done and check for existence of this blob. These could work but seem a bit unatural, is there a better solution ? Thanks a  lot!

Comment: Is the web role going to maintain a connection this whole time?  The typical pattern is to have the client poll (via AJAX), and then it seems quite natural for the web role to in turn poll a blob or a table to see if the work is done.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to follow a bit more experimental path, you could also try looking at [Phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/). This is a project that compiles PHP code to .NET, so it may be possible to run it directly on Azure and nicely collaborate with F# (Phalanger has a few language extensions that allow you to call any .NET objects and some [API for calling Phalanger objects](http://tomasp.net/blog/ducktyping-in-phalaner.aspx) from C#).

I was involved in the project some time ago, but it is now beign developed by other people (and as you can see from the check-ins, it is quite active again and they would surely be interested in collaborating to resolve possible Azure issues). If you were interested, let me know - I can give you some contacts, so that you can discuss the Phalanger status on Azure with them.

Comment: Unless you want to call into .NET code from your PHP code, I don't see why he would use Phalanger instead of regular PHP.

Comment: as @smarx says the Php does not need to directly call the .Net code. In anycase thanks for offering to put me in contact.